# Setting VLAN from CSV File in PowerCLI Script

Tags: powershell, csv, automation, vmware, powercli

I am trying to compile a PowerCLI script to help automate the creation of VMs from a CSV file's data. Currently the script I am running looks like this:

```
# Specify vCenter Server, vCenter Server username and vCenter Server user password
 write-host “Please specify vCenter Server and enter credentials” -foreground green
 $vc = read-Host "Connect to which vCenter Server?"
 write-host “Connecting to vCenter Server $vc” -foreground green

 $CSVPath = "$ScriptRoot\PROD_VMRequestTEST.xlsx.csv"    

 Connect-VIServer -Server $vc

 $CSVFile = Import-Csv -Path $CSVPath

 Import-Csv -Path $CSVPath

# Specify vCenter Server Virtual Machine & Templates folder
 $Folder = “Discovered virtual machine”

#
# Specify the vSphere Cluster

$Cluster = 'vSphere 5.5 RND'

$esx = Get-Cluster $Cluster | Get-VMHost -State connected

Import-Csv -Path $CSVPath | %{

  Write-Host “Creation of VM $_.Name initiated”  -ForegroundColor green

  New-VM -Name $_.Name -VMHost ($esx | Get-Random) -Location $Folder

  Write-Host “Power On of the  VM $_.name initiated”  -ForegroundColor green

  Start-VM -VM $_.Name -confirm:$false -RunAsync

}
```

I have encountered a few examples online dealing with setting the VLAN via PowerCLI but none of them seem to relate directly to my example of using the CSV file to determine the VLAN.

One example I tried using with my script was:

```
$VMhost = Get-vmhost $_.VMHost  
$PortGroup = Get-VirtualPortgroup -name $_.VLAN -VMhost $VMhost
```

However, I get errors relating to the -Name argument in that line.

Comment: What errors are you getting? More information is rarely harmful and less makes it harder to help you.

Comment: @Matt The error I am getting reads "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. Provide an argument that is not null or empty".

Comment: well, the obvious question, why is it null?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I probably don't fully understand how that line is working together with the rest of the script (I am new at this) but my impression is that it should be calling on the VLAN column from my CSV file - which is not null from my review of the document's contents.

Comment: We would need to to see your source file header and a sample line maybe. VLAN is either not a column or the value for that row is blank. Watch out for leading and trailing spaces in both the columns and their values.

Comment: You should notice your `write-host` lines do not print what you expect no? It should look like this `Write-Host "Power On of the  VM $($_.name) initiated"  -ForegroundColor green`. Consider doing a line that that for VLAN as well. `Write-Host "VLAN - '$($_.VLAN)'"  -ForegroundColor green`

Comment: @Matt You got it - There were spaces added from my VBA script (for unknown reason) that I ran on the Excel spreadsheet. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

On the script context, I believe the error is causing because one of the columns value seems empty(in your case its **Name**). I can see that you are getting all the values in a foreach loop. I would recommend you to create a sample csv, insert only 2 set of data and see if it works. This way atleast you can narrow down the issue.

Hope this helps...!!!